# Is scikit image random_walker patented?

Tags: python, scikit-image

Is there a patent associated with the [skimage.segmentation.random_walker](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#random-walker) implementation in scikit-image? Is it free to use in a commercial project?

Comment: you can check out their [licence](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)

Comment: Well, it's not quite that simple.  *LOTS* of libraries (including OpenCV) implement algorithms covered by patents, but don't mention that in their licenses.  Scikit-image, however, never includes patented algorithms, at least as far as we know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more about the scikit-image license: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/license.html
If you use it in source or binary form, you only have to mention the copyright, conditions and disclaimer you'll find in link.
In the [random.walker](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.random_walker) there are no individual licensing specification via LICENSE.txt, so the general scikit-image license is applied to the `random.walker` as well.

I made a general patent search, there were patented of random walker algorithm application for medicine purposes by Siemens US in  but it is not active anymore (pat. no. US7729537)